# Difference between Content Hub CMP and Content Hub One?

Tags: content-hub

What is the difference between `Content Hub CMP` and `Content Hub One`?

Both can be utilized for content management and the development of lightweight websites using Experience Edge.

But when should each be utilized, and what are their respective advantages and disadvantages?

Answer (score 0):

**Content Marketing Platform** (CMP) is a module in Content Operations to effectively plan, manage, and collaborate on content strategy · Streamline your production by orchestrating many simultaneous task streams. Basically if you manage content either in multiple languages or different downstream channels. CMP enables you to care only about the content and all of its localisations and when ready push these to end user channels.

**Content Hub One** was designed to empower the marketers and developers and its platform’s simple UI enables marketers to create and update content independently and frequently with ease and allows the developers to focus on building customer experiences.

**Comparison:**

CMP and Content Hub ONE are for managing your content. To keep it simple both can be used to distribute content to downstream platforms. Also CH ONE at one point was branched from the Content Hub code base.

The major difference is that Content Hub CMP comes as part of Content Hub – Content Operations. Where Content Hub ONE is for customers that need a easy to use and convenient solution.

Content Hub ONE includes a wide range of features such as digital asset management, content creation and management, collaboration tools, product content management, and workflow automation. It's suitable for businesses looking for a centralized hub for content and digital assets. And CMP includes features like content planning and calendaring, content creation and distribution, SEO optimization, analytics, and campaign performance tracking.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, But in your last paragraph you are talking about Content Hub not Content Hub one, I think there is a typo.

Comment: @Gautam Here is a link from a colleague that talks about the difference between CMP and Content Hub One https://timmarsh.co.uk/2023/06/16/what-happens-to-sitecore-content-hub-cmp-now-that-content-hub-one-is-here/. Hope you find it useful.